# 2 controller and 1 view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 controllers, task and user.

I need to create a view for "create task to users". So I need "a user list" and "create task" view together.

Usually views inherit from only 1 class.

How can I create a view working with 2 classes?

Have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view can't and should not inherit from 2 classes.

Create a view model for your user which has a list of task view models.

Comment: my view model now as below;


public class CreateTaskViewModel
    {
        public CreateTaskViewModel(List<MU_User> user, MU_Task task)
        {
            this.Users = user;
            this.Task = task;
        }

        public List<MU_User> Users{ get; private set; }
        public MU_Task Task { get; private set; }  
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can implement each View (user list and create task) as partial views (.ascx user controls), and call each of these from within your View (.aspx page).

Rendering a partial view is done by using the RenderPartial method:

```
this.Html.RenderPartial("UserList");
this.Html.RenderPartial("CreateTask");
```

This will allow you to reuse and combine Views accross different Views (pages).

As AmisL points out, you can pass different parts of your ViewModel to each partial view.

Comment: And it's good to remember that if partial view receives null as view model, it tries to pick up view model from view. That can cause a data type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

A View can receive any class as Model, so just write a custom class, like:

```
public class UserListAndTasks
{
    public IQuerable<User> UserList;
    public Task Task;
}
```

Then, in your View, you can use partials:

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("UserList", Model.UserList); %>
<%= Html.RenderPartial("CreateTask", Model.Task); %>
```